# c# Cut non-transparent blocks in image

Tags: c#, winforms, image-processing

Suppose we have a 32BppARGB image:
[image]

i would like to crop every block and save it as a seperated image without the transpert pixels in the side!

This is my code so far:

```
  private unsafe Bitmap CodeImage(Bitmap bmp)
    {
     
        Bitmap bmpRes = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
     

        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
    

        int stride = bmData.Stride;

     
        int nWidth = bmp.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp.Height;
        int minX = 10000 ;
        int minY = 1000;
        int width=0;
        var height= 0;

        bool found = false;
        for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
        {
            byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
            p += y * stride;

           
            for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
            {




                if (p[3] != 0)  //Check if pixel is transpert;
                {


                    found = true;
                    if (x < minX)
                        minX = x;
                    if (y < minY)
                        minY = y;
                    if (x > width)
                        width = x;
                    if (y > height)
                        height = y;


                }

                else
                  
                {
                    if (found)
                    {
                        Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(minX, minY, width - minX, height-minY);
                        MessageBox.Show(temp.Top.ToString() + "," + temp.Left.ToString() +", "+ temp.Width.ToString()+", "+temp.Height.ToString());                            

                        
                        return bmp.Clone(temp, bmp.PixelFormat);
                    }
                }



                p += 4;
             
               
            }
        }


        return null;

    }
```

As you can see im trying to identify the first blue block for example, and when the pixels are not transparent anymore so the block is over and i store the dimensions of the rectangle in `temp`. it works actually good, for this image it prints  a rect with this bounds (200,800,399,0)almost works  but there is one problem with the height...somehow its 0 and i have no idea why... maybe there's is a simple type i cant figure out.
Thanks for everything

Comment: It is normal that the height is not correct. Your code does not scan the rectangle to determine the width and height but **only** the first line of the rectangle. At that point `height` is the y coordinate of the top left corner of the rectangle (height = minY). When the line finishes (p[3] = 0) then your code exits with the wrong height : height - minY = 0.

Comment: A solution is to let your code scan the whole image. Remove the `else` statement and add the `if(found)...` code outside the double for loop.

Comment: Also your check should be `if (p[0] == 255 && p[1] == 0 && p[2] == 0 && p[3] != 0)`

Comment: It's not necessarily actually to check the whole rgba only the alpha channel. But thanks . About the solution, I don't think I understand what you mean. ..could you explain a little bit more?  Or just edit my code according to your suggestion? Thanks @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment you should scan the whole image to get the correct height. Your code scans only the forst line of the blue rectangle. It doesnt go to the second line because it exits. For the blue rectangle the code should be:

```
private unsafe Bitmap CodeImage(Bitmap bmp)
{

    Bitmap bmpRes = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

    BitmapData bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);


    IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;


    int stride = bmData.Stride;


    int nWidth = bmp.Width;
    int nHeight = bmp.Height;
    int minX = 10000 ;
    int minY = 1000;
    int width=0;
    var height= 0;

    bool found = false;
    for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)
    {
        byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
        p += y * stride;


        for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
        {

            if (p[0] == 255 && p[1] == 0 && p[2] == 0 && p[3] != 0)  //Check if pixel is blue;
            {


                found = true;
                if (x < minX)
                    minX = x;
                if (y < minY)
                    minY = y;
                if (x > width)
                    width = x;
                if (y > height)
                    height = y;


            }

            p += 4;


        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
        //add one for the width and height
        Rectangle temp = new Rectangle(minX, minY, width - minX + 1, height - minY + 1);
        MessageBox.Show(temp.Top.ToString() + "," + temp.Left.ToString() + ", " + temp.Width.ToString() + ", " + temp.Height.ToString());


        return bmp.Clone(temp, bmp.PixelFormat);
    }

    return null;

}
```

[image]

For this simple example (top left image) we can have 4 different combinations of rectangles. So what will happen if we have a more complex situation?

Comment: no man that's the point! that i dont really know the rectangle pixels... the image above was just as example... it actually depended in the user input... i just want to store each block(which is not transparnent!-so we just can check if(p[3]!=0) into a list of Rectangles ... in other words so save each block bounds... so i **must** to stop in the moment i detect a transparent pixel... i hope you understand and could fix my code :) thank you very much man! for everything! @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε

Comment: @Slashy Your problem is way too difficult to be solved. The combinations of number and shapes of the non transparent pixels are huge! You need to compine all of them into rectangles and that is ... not to say impossible, but too much work.

Comment: do you really think so? isnt it about a bounty? :)

Comment: @Slashy However you can get all the non-transparent pixels as rectangles with height equal to 1. It is like scanning its line. When you find a non-transparent pixel you create a new rectangle and when you find a transparent one you "close" (I mean you know the width) the rectangle.

Comment: actually im doing it for a screen sharing program... so it wont really help me :(